# How to make a path transition nicely in D3.js, with different dates (or x axis data)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two sets of data that I'd like to use on the same line and transition between each set of data  However when I do this the line has a weird animation. I'd like to to simply morph from where it was before but hide/add the part of the line with no data/data

so lets say this is the data...

```
var allData = 
[{"date":"1/1/1950","data1":3.4,"data2":null},
{"date":"2/1/1950","data1":3.8,"data2":null},
{"date":"3/1/1950","data1":4.0,"data2":4.4},
{"date":"4/1/1950","data1":3.9,"data2":4.3}];
```

And here is the x scale that I call in the x axis

```
xScaleTime
   .range([0, chartWidth])
   .domain(d3.extent(allData, function(d) { return +d.date; }));
```

and this is the line function

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return xScaleTime(d.date);});
```

so I select the path and pass it it data1 and call the line function...

```
lineFunction.y(function(d) { return yScale(d[data1]);});   
d3.select(path).transition().duration(500).attr("d", lineFunction(allData));
```

then I select the path and do the same for data2...

```
lineFunction.y(function(d) { return yScale(d[data2]);});
d3.select(path).transition().duration(500).attr("d", lineFunction(allData));
```

Ive tried adding defined() before calling the function and this does shorten the line but the animation looks weird as if the line is redrawing from the left side of the chart instead of from where it was earlier when I called data1  and it also looks weird/choppy when I run defined() again, adding back all of the data

```
lineFunction.defined(function(d) { return d.data2 != null; })
```

Comment: try this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/ also use d3.select()

Comment: Changed to d3.select where needed.  But not sure I understand the constancy link

Comment: You need to use joins: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/